# Save into the file with value instead of placeholder

Tags: java, file, save, velocity, placeholder

I use Apache Velocity, so I have a *.vm file, the content of which "Hello $name".

```
Velocity.init();
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
context.put("name", "Velocity");
StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
Velocity.mergeTemplate("testtemplate.vm", context, w);
System.out.println(" template : " + w);
```

The result of this code is -

```
template : Hello Velocity!
```

My task is to save this result into the file. How can I save it so that in the file instead of the placeholder was a real value ("Hello Velocity!" in this particular case).

Answer (score 2):

`Velocity.mergeTemplate` accepts a writer. In this case you pass a `StringWriter` which just dumps everything in a string. You can either pass a `FileWriter` instead, which can save the output directly in the target file, or manually print into a file the result of `w.toString()`;

```
FileWriter w = new FileWriter("/path/to/targetFile.txt");
Velocity.mergeTemplate("testtemplate.vm", context, w);
w.close();
```